# log of probability density function integral separation?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I have know the following relationships that I know to be true:

$$ \int_X f(x) \mathbf{log}[f(x)]dx \geq  \int_Y g(y) \mathbf{log}[g(y)]dy \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) $$
$$ \int_X f(x) dx = \int_Y g(y) dy = 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (2)$$
$$ f(x) \geq 0, g(y) \geq 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$, we can see that $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are probability density functions.

<strike>If this is all I know, is there anything I can say about the relationship between $f(x)$ and $g(y)$?  What I would like to say, is that $f(x) \geq g(y)$, but I don't think that is true, or even if it is I can't prove it.  Without the constraint in $(2)$, it is possible to come up with a counter-example to $f(x) \geq g(y)$, but I am not sure how the constraints in $(2)$ and $(3)$ are affecting the problem.</strike>

Can $\mathbf{log}$ in $(1)$ be replaced by any monotonic function and the inequality in $(1)$ still hold true?

I have tried something similar to Integration by Parts to try to separate out the integral in $(1)$, but it seems to be leading to more complicated expressions.  I have also tried to look at inequalities like Jensen's, but it doesn't seem to directly apply to my case.

Thank you so much in advance!

*** Edited Question in light of comments ***

Comment: What if $X=[0;1.125],Y=[0,1], f(x) = \{0.25$ if $x \in [0,1); 6$ if $x \in [1;1.125]\} ; g(y) = 1$ if $y \in [0;1]$

Comment: Property (1) just says that the differential entropy of $X$ is less than that of $Y$.  Also, one pdf can never be greater than another everywhere unless they are equal, since they both have to integrate to 1.

Comment: @Thoth thank you for the reminder, seems I forgot the obvious that one pdf cannot be greater than the other unless they are equal b/c of $(2)$.

Regarding differential entropy, I understand that, I was hoping to glean some insight into the shape of $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ from the known relationships above ... but as you said, that may not be possible.